# How to use two base tables in one custom entity Drupal 8?

Tags: 8, entities, database

```
base_table = "test_table"
```

The is the annotation in the custom entity file, is it possible for me to use two tables for the same entity. something like this

```
 *   base_table = array(
 *     "test_table1" => "test_table1",
 *     "test_table2" => "test_table2",
 *     ),
```

Comment: I doubt it; entities are synonymous with a single base table. Two base tables equals two different entity types by definition

Comment: Makes sense, but don't you think it would be a good feature to have? so instead of one long table many columns , we could have two of them that could be used by one just entity?

Comment: Not really - the number of columns in a table doesn't realistically make a difference anyway, unless you're at the point where you've got so many that it's clear the underlying design is wrong. The only thing it would do is make querying entity data more awkward, not to mention slow it down somewhat

Comment: Seconding Clive's comments. There is no reason to be breaking the columns into two tables.